# Need to change radio value if a input has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, stripe-payments

I'm desperate.
I'm making a credit card auto system using Stripe Payment plugin, but I'm kind of lost. Anyway, when the credit card is MasterCard (for example), the card number input receive "mastercard" class - what give it a background image with the flag of mastercard.
But I need to chance the value of a radio input with it. So here is my unfunctional code:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="numero" type="tel" class="validate" required  name="cartaoNumero" disabled='disabled' style="transition:none;" />
<input type="radio" id="credito1" name="codigoBandeira" value="visa" />
```

**JQUERY (or attempt to):**

```
    function mudarradio() {
        if ($("#numero").hasClass( "visa" )) {

            $('input:radio[name=codigoBandeira]').val(['visa']);

            } else if ($("#numero").hasClass( "mastercard" )) {

            $('input:radio[name=codigoBandeira]').val(['mastercard']);
        }
        $('body').on('mouseenter', mudarradio);
    };
```

Like, when the user use a Mastercard number, `#numero` input receive `mastercard` class.
Nothing happens even when `#numero` has a different class...
Ok, I know, it is a mess. But I'm a front-end progammer, so.. HELPP!!!!

Comment: You've explained what you need but you haven't explained the actual problem yet, also within your `mudarradio` function you bind `mouseenter` event but jQuery will keep rebinding this every function call so I'm not sure if this is a good idea (when hovering over the addressbar and back into the website for instance this will duplicate the handler)

Comment: My problem is that radio value isn't changing. Nothing happens even when `#numero` has a different class... I'll edit my question with these new informations.

Comment: Is this what you need @Igor : http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1572/

Comment: So, change the first input class to `mastercard` and run the code again you'll see that nothing happens with the radio's value.

Comment: You need to remove the brackets from val(['mastercard']); and val(['visa']); like val('visa'); and val('mastercard'); to get it working @Igor

Comment: Look: http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1573/  
`#numero` already comes with `mastercard` class and even without the brackets, nothing happens with the radio value.

Comment: Where are you looking at the radio value. I just checked the value using inspect element and it is "mastercard". http://imgur.com/2dQBhe1

Comment: And besides that FRONT-END Programming domain also consists jQuery I guess. Not sure though.

Comment: Solved! Thank you, Amit! But you didn't make an answer :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with changing this line `$('body').on('mouseenter', mudarradio);`

to target a change to the input box, rather than a mouse entering the body? Is there a reason you set it up that way? try this instead

`$('#numero').on('change', mudarradio);`

Comment: It is a good point, really better, I'll change it. But how do I solve radio unchangeble value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going for by setting the val of a radio button. radio buttons are either checked or unchecked. If it were my page I would have a seperate radio button for each potential value and then select the appropriate radio button like so `$(':radio[value=mastercard]').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Believe me, there are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy. I made an animation based on some radio buttons and the back-end programmer made these radio buttons (whose sole function was to make the animation worked) necessary for the form...

Comment: @godmode: I believe this comment was for me :D

Comment: Idk, I'm really confused hahahaha. Anyway, SOLVED!!! Thank you, godmode and Amit!

Comment: np @Igor, happy to help

Comment: make sure you mark an answer so the question can be closed

Comment: Well, I made an answer for myself with all informations that I got from you, but I can't accept my own answer as an ANSWER yet...